# HTTPS Auto-Login Probs

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a C# script to login automatically to a website and download a report.

I have managed to login to the site. Effectively the steps are:

1) Get login form
2) Sent login/pass with cookies
3) Logged In
4) Ask for Report & Download

The problem I am having is that 4).. doesn't work. It just keeps redirecting me to login form again even when I sent all cookies and I am logged in.

I know the URL is correct because when I login via the browser the report appears immediately ?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or similar to record a browser performing the operation. Then record a session with your program attempting to perform the operation (and failing).

From those two traces see what the differences are. That will tell you what additional browser emulation you need to do.

It might be:

1. Referer header
2. hidden fields
3. POST requests

Or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a cookie-bassed session management? I.e. does the site send a cookie that identifies your session as response(-header) to a successful login? If so do you send this cookie as part of the request in step 4?

Comment: hi! thanks so much for the response. yep - i am sending all cookies that are required even for the step 4